# Printing JP chars in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to print JP chars. I am using java 8 and freemarker 2.3.31.
I have following code,

```
output starts
${(("こんにちは世界")?right_pad(12,"-"))[0..*12]}
${(("こんにちは")?right_pad(12,"-"))[0..*12]}
output ends
output starts
${(("こんにちは世界")?right_pad(12))[0..*12]}*
${(("こんにちは")?right_pad(12))[0..*12]}*
output ends
```

and below is the output. Why is it in not ending in same place.

```
output starts
こんにちは世界-----
こんにちは-------
output ends
output starts
こんにちは世界     *
こんにちは       *
output ends
```

what am  i missing? Same thing when i do in english works fine and both the lines starts and ends at same place. I tried adding `<#ftl encoding="Shift_JIS">` to my ftl file.But no luck. Can someone help. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Japanese you should use the wider ideographic space (U+3000) instead normal space. That is, `?right_pad(12, '\x3000')`.

If you need a similarly wide dash, that's U+30FC, so like `?right_pad(12, '\x30FC')`.

All these can of course be typed directly as well, like `?right_pad(12, 'ー')`, but in that case be careful with the template file encoding.

Comment: There is still some difference in the ending,  i changed my code as                               output starts
${(("こんにちは世界")?right_pad(12,'\x3000'))[0..*12]}*
${(("こんにちは")?right_pad(12,'\x3000'))[0..*12]}*
output ends..                                                                                                                                           output was same as before.

Comment: While copy pasting the output in SO i noticed that it became correct ie both the line ended in same place (same didnt happen in eclipse or notepad+). I code in eclipse (UTF8 is set as default there) . In my ftl i was not having any econding setting(because i had set the encoding in freemarker configuration(UTF8 even there).  )    what is the difference?.

Comment: i tried with https://try.freemarker.apache.org/ editor. It works fine there also. Is there any setting im missing in eclipse

Comment: I'm not sure what you did and how. Maybe in some fonts the ideographic space and that special dash has wrong width? Have you tried looking at the output with different fonts?

Comment: As of encoding... so, when you edit the template file, the editor has to think that it's in UTF-8. Also the FreeMarker `Configuration` `defaultEncoding` need to be UTF-8. Then the output `Writer` passed to FreeMarker has to encode the output with UTF-8 (if that's how it ends up in an output file). Finally when you look at the output, whatever you use for it has to believe it's in UTF-8. Something that can be confusing here is that if you write '\x3000', as opposed to directly entering that character, then template encoding issues won't affect that.

Answer (score 3):

It is not ending at the same place because the length of a Japanese character is different from the length of the `-`.

The solution would be to use a Japanese character with the same width as a kanji, and the same meaning as the dash. I don't know if such a character exists (maybe U+30FB: `・` )

Comment: Ya i was trying with \\u0020(unicode space) but it is printing as it is. How do  you use unicode chars in freemarker?. any suggestions or examples would be great help.

Comment: @NoOne \u0020 is just the normal space with a different notation. Every character is a UNICODE character.